# Object Nested Uint8Array(32) to String to btoa to localStorage to atob to Uint8Array(32)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, base64, uint8array

My skills in javascript are minimal and I am unsure of how to get the original Uint8Array(32) after it's been sent to localStorage, decoded and converted back to Uint8Array(32). Below you will see that I tried stringifying a private key then base64 encoding it so that it gets sent to localStorage for later usage:

```
window.genSKey = function()
{
var secretKey = eccrypto.generatePrivate();
console.log(secretKey);
var skey = JSON.stringify(secretKey);
var SKey = window.btoa(skey);
localStorage.setItem("skey", SKey);
console.log(SKey);
alert(`your private key is ${SKey}`);
return;
}
```

Here you will notice that I am trying to get the private key so that I can generate the corresponding public key by taking the base64 encoded string from localStorage and creating a new Uint8Array from it:

```
window.base642Array = function(base64) {
    var binStr = window.atob(base64);
    console.log("binStr"+ binStr);
    var l = binStr.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(l);
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

```
window.genPKey = function()
{
    console.log("getSKey flag: 0");

    var SKey = getSKey();

    console.log("getSKey flag: 1");

    var publicKey;
    if(SKey != null || undefined)
    {
        console.log(SKey);

        console.log("getSKey flag: 2");

        publicKey = eccrypto.getPublic(SKey);

        console.log("getSKey flag: 3");

        localStorage.setItem("pkey", window.btoa(JSON.stringify(publicKey)));

        return;

    }

    console.log("getSKey flag: alt");

    genSKey();
    genPKey();

    return;
```

```
window.getSKey = function()
{
    console.log("getSKey flag: 0");

    var SKey = localStorage.getItem("skey");

    var skey = base642Array(SKey);

    console.log("getSKey flag: 1");

    console.log("getSKey flag: 2");

    console.log(skey);

    return skey;
}
```

and here you will see that the results going in are different than the results that came out:

in

```
Uint8Array(32) [247, 145, 236, 54, 52, 10, 202, 187, 35, 79, 42, 141, 230, 76, 228, 2, 109, 228, 72, 92, 221, 139, 235, 147, 244, 10, 149, 220, 196, 175, 11, 128]
0: 247
1: 145
2: 236
3: 54
4: 52
5: 10
6: 202
7: 187
8: 35
9: 79
10: 42
11: 141
12: 230
13: 76
14: 228
15: 2
16: 109
17: 228
18: 72
19: 92
20: 221
21: 139
22: 235
23: 147
24: 244
25: 10
26: 149
27: 220
28: 196
29: 175
30: 11
31: 128
offset: (...)
parent: (...)
buffer: (...)
byteLength: (...)
byteOffset: (...)
length: (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
__proto__: Uint8Array
```

out

```
ArrayBuffer(141) {}
[[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(141)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 140]
__proto__: TypedArray
[[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(141)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 140]
__proto__: TypedArray
byteLength: (...)
__proto__: ArrayBuffer
byteLength: (...)
constructor: ƒ ArrayBuffer()
slice: ƒ slice()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "ArrayBuffer"
get byteLength: ƒ byteLength()
__proto__: Object
[[IsDetached]]: false
```

I think the problem might be using JSON.stringify to turn the nested Uint8Array into a string, but I am not sure of other methods that will make this function well.

Why wasn't the object input the same as the object output? I would like to learn how to do this, help would mean the world to me.

Comment: The input/output do not correspond to the `console.log` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- Although you use `JSON.stringify`, you never use the reverse operation, i.e. `JSON.parse`
- You use `charCodeAt`, but you never used the reverse operation, i.e. `String.fromCharCode`. `charCodeAt` has no relation to what you did to make the string, so this should be dropped.
- When debugging such issues, you should eliminate steps. For instance, you would find that the following steps are not related to your problem:

  - storing and retrieving from local storage;
  - converting to and from base64 encoding;
  - using the encryption library

  The problem is in converting the typed array to string and back.

The translation to string and the translation back to the typed array are not each other's reversal at all.

To fix this, I would suggest to change the calls you have to `JSON.stringify`, so that you stringify to an array notation (starting with `[`) and not to a plain object notation (starting with `{`). So change:

```
JSON.stringify(secretKey);
```

to:

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from(secretKey));
```

Then to turn that string back to a typed array, use `JSON.parse`:

```
new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(str))
```

Here is a little demo without the steps that are not related:

```js
function fromTypedArrayToString(arr) {
    return JSON.stringify([...arr]);
}

function fromStringToTypedArray(str) {
    return new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(str));
}

function compareTypedArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}  

// Demo: make a typed array with all possible values
let arr = new Uint8Array([...Array(256).keys()]);
let str = fromTypedArrayToString(arr);
let arr2 = fromStringToTypedArray(str);
let consistent = compareTypedArrays(arr, arr2);
console.log("Is the result consistent:", consistent);
```

You should be able to apply this to your code, adding step by step:

- base64 encoding, although I cannot see the benefit of that: the string will grow with 30% in size. You could do without this.
- local storage
- encryption module

Before proceeding with the next step keep checking that the operation can be reversed giving you back the original values of the typed array, as I did in the snippet above.

Comment: A lot of useful information, the arrays did return true but I am still getting the error from https://www.npmjs.com/package/eccrypto that the private key is "bad" when being passed to create the public key. As far as this question goes you helped me solve this problem, but it lead me to another which is unfortunate. So my guess is that it's the library itself plus the keys not being equivalent are the problems.